# Struts2 use toString method instead of TypeConverter

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Struts2 application and I'm trying to use a custom type converter.

```
<s:a action="documentView">  
  <s:param name="documentTag" value="constructTag(#aDocumentIndex)"/>  
  view  
</s:a>
```

`constructTag` is just an action method which return a `documentTag`

```
public DocumentTag constructTag(DocumentIndex documentIndex) {  
  return new DocumentTag(documentIndex);  
}
```

When page is rendered `toString` method is used instead of the type converter. Why ?

PS : Type converter is correctly working when `documentView` action is called.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want to have rendered?

Comment: For moment, documentTag.toString method is calling documentTagConverter.convertToString. Then program is working correctly. Question is why struts call documentTag.toString and not documentTagConverter.convertToString.

Comment: Type converters apply to setting attributes on the action and not the view. constructTag() returns a String, you are invoking this with an OGNL expression, the setting of action parameters is done via the ParamsInterceptor (?) regardless of the name, the interceptors are not involved during OGNL execution, so toString is expected. You can manually create an instance of your type converter using s:bean tag and then invoke its methods in the value attribute or you can add a static method to the converter, allow static method access and call it more directly.